# iOS Push notifications in cyrillic

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hullo,
I am sending push notifications by means of this php snippet:

```
// Build the binary notification
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

it works fine and good with latin languages but, when I try to send a russian notification, nothing arrives, notwithstanding the logs confirm the correct delivery.

> notify fbartolom@gmail.com for language ru Saturday 1st of March 2014
>   08:15:59 PM notify
>   246e2e720c0f307ef3887922d72b6b6886fa19b44b6dbae7cda8913fe149958e con
>   Ваше активное бронирование было прервана пользователем.
>   dopo*****:/var/www/html/php/push/taxi/distribution/ck.pem
>   deviceToken:246e2e720c0f307ef3887922d72b6b6886fa19b44b6dbae7cda8913fe149958eConnected
>   to APNS invio payload{"aps":{"alert":"\u0412\u0430\u0448\u0435
>   \u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u043e\u0435
>   \u0431\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435
>   \u0431\u044b\u043b\u043e
>   \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0440\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0430
>   \u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u043c.","sound":"default"}}Message
>   successfully delivered
>   I read about issues on the length of the packet, but in both phases it calculates it while sending the message and so it should be the correct length.
>   Any idea about what to do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried sending just one or 2 cyrillic characters?

Comment: Actually for some strange reason, sometimes the notification arrive, but when it happens it is just comprised of a sequence question marks and spaces, like if the UTF8 conversion were lost at Apple's. I will try to post just a few characters to see if it changes.

Comment: In fact just word Ваше gets through, may it be a problem of length while converting or what? And in that case any experience of the maximum one?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and I'm leaning towards a "size" problem.
Try using [mb_strlen](https://www.php.net/mb_strlen) in your code instead of strlen as strlen cannot accurate calculate length of multi-byte characters.

Comment: Thanks, I did that: // Build the binary notification
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, mb_strlen($msg)); but still no way, no message altogether: that is a section of the payload: payload{"aps":{"alert":"\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u043b\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u044b!\u0417\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0442\u0430\u043a\u0441\u0438 \u043f.","sound":"default"}}Message successfully delivered; confirming the correct delivery.

Comment: Actually I set the charset to utf-8 and now it works, up to a certain lenght. This is longest string I may successfully deliver: Комплименты!Заказанное такси принято бр. If I add one more character, nothing arrives. I suspect each cyrilic character occupies more bytes than latin languages do and, so exceeding a certain total lenght, the actual occupation exceeds the allottment, strangely returning no error, though. May someone confirm this feeling? This also opens a can of worms with languages like Chinese, too.

Comment: Most non-latin letters will consume up to 4 bytes each (significantly more than latin letters) which indeed means the payload length will be less. As long as this 256-byte limit is in place, you're kinda stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the optimal solution is to send english strings and localize them in the app. The only downsize of it is that you need to submit an update each time you want to add a new notification type.